# ¿Como recibir 2 consultas diferentes desde phpmysql por un solo fetch de javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Agradezco alguien me ayude para saber cómo retornar 2 resultados de consultas diferentes por medio de un solo fetch de Javascript. Con este sumo, pero requiero traer otra respuesta.

```
let imprimeTotal2 = new FormData()
imprimeTotal2.append("codigo", codigo)
fetch(link_imprime2,
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: imprimeTotal2,
        mode: "cors" //Default cors, no-cors, same-origin
    }).then(rta => rta.json())
    .then(imprime2 => {
        let arrayimprime2 = imprime2.split(",")
        let i = arrayimprime2.length

        sum2 = 0
        totalAdd2 = 0

        parseInt(totalAdd2)

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            sum2 = arrayimprime2[j]
            sum2 = parseInt(sum2)

            totalAdd2 = totalAdd2 + sum2

        }

    })
```

Comment: hola te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: bueno una vez que hagas el tour necesito que me respondas esta pregunta: ¿si ya lograste enviar datos a php y en php tienes esos dos datos... que es lo que has intentando hacer para retornarlos, investigaste algo???

Comment: te dare una pista... implementa JSON ...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendación Francisco. Sí, ya logro traer datos desde mysql. Pero necesito otra consulta para trabajar unas variables y sumatorias pero no se cómo hacerlo. Había creado otro fetch pero al utilizar la variables fuera de ese ámbito no puedo utilizarlas

Comment: usa promise y lo anidas ... asi sabes que solo entrara al segundo promise si el primero se cumple XD

Comment: mira lo que dice ChatGPT aveces cuando no tenemo muy claro como resolver algo no puede ayudar a tener una idea... solo no confies en el codigo y revisalo antes de usarlo: https://chat.openai.com/share/0764a7e2-a584-49b2-a7a3-c5b061e61772

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco. Voy a revisar como anidar promise.

Comment: No entiendo el problema, como sería el segundo `fetch` ??? y ese segundo fetch necesita el valor de `totalAdd2 `?? o algún otro dato?

Comment: ¿Realmente hace falta un segundo fetch? Si del lado del cliente nada cambia después del primero, puedes realizarlo todo en ese primer fetch. Otra cosa sería que el cliente necesite los datos del primero para luego, en base a esos datos tomar una decisión, agregar datos adicionales, etc, en cuyo caso sí estaría justificado un segundo fetch. Piénsalo como un viaje a Australia. No pagarías dos billetes de avión para dos viajes si al hacer el primero ya tienes todo lo que tienes que llevar a Australia (el servidor). Sería absurdo hacer tal cosa.